# Why I am getting this slight deviation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, error-propagation

I have solved this equation by two method

> √3a = 50+a

> Method 1

√3a-a =50

a(√3-1) = 50

a= 50/(√3-1)

a= 50/0.73 = **68.4**

> Method 2

a(√3-1) = 50

a = 50/(√3-1)

a =50(√3+1)/2.  [by rationalizing]

a =25 * 2.73

a = **68.25**

Note : I have taken √3 = 1.73 in both of the above method
Still got different value of " a ".Can you please tell why this slight deviation has occured

Comment: Precisely because you have taken $\sqrt 3 = 1.73$, or rather, *imprecisely*...

Comment: @player3236 But I have taken √3=1.73 is both the methods .

Comment: @HarshGautam $\sqrt3$ is a number such that $\frac{\sqrt3+1}{2}=\frac1{\sqrt3-1}$, but $1.73$ is not a number such that $\frac{1.73+1}{2}=\frac1{1.73-1}$ (if it were, then it would either be $\sqrt3$ or $-\sqrt3$). Approximations not only prevent the final result from being exactly the one it would be, but also invalidate intermediate identities, making therefore the approximate result depend on the specific sequence of computational steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you are assuming that $\sqrt{3}=1.73$. This is incorrect: it should be $\sqrt{3} \approx 1.73$. Because you are only using the approximate value of $\sqrt{3}$, it is only natural that you get an approximate answer.

It is best to work through questions like these without rounding any figures until the very end. This is because small rounding errors can accumulate. For example, if I take $\sqrt{3}$ as $1.73$, then $1000\sqrt{3}$ would be approximated as $1730$. This is more than $2$ units away from the true answer of $1732.050\ldots$. Depending on when and where you round figures, the error that results could be marginal, or it could be much greater. In your example, the true answer is
$$
a=\frac{50}{\sqrt{3}-1} \approx 68.301 \, .
$$
Because you rounded early, both of your answers are a little off!